# Angular 5: Generic type 'HttpRequest<T>'

Tags: angular, http, angular-http, angular-httpclient

After I writed interceptor I get an error:

```
error TS2314: Generic type 'HttpRequest<T>' requires 1 type argument(s).
```

This is my source code :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpErrorResponse, HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { UserService } from '@dockers/core/user/user.service';

@Injectable()
export class ErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(private userService: UserService) {}

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        return next.handle(req).catch((err: any) => {
            console.log('Caught error', err);
            if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse && err.status === 401) {
                this.userService.logoutUser();
            }
            return Observable.throw(err);
        });
    }
}
```

Any solutions and help would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is `<T>` in `'HttpRequest<T>'` should be a concrete type complex or primitive